Comparing if a Instant has passed a Duration in java
Problem
I am currently trying to fix an issue with my Java Code. Essentially, I have to variables: currentTime of Type Instant and activeAfterSecond of type Duration (from the java.time package).
Basically what I want to do is check whether currentTime has already passed the duration (or reached it). So in pseudocode something like this:
if(currentTime >= duration){
   // do something
}

Obviously something like this does not work, as Instants and Durations cannot be compared to one another. I have been trying to figure out what method from the java.time.Instant and java.time.Duration packages would be best for comparing (e.g. using something like getSeconds() from the Duration package) but haven't been able to find a proper, feasible solution.
Does anyone have any idea how I could solve this issue? Help would be appreciated!
Solution
(based on what Diego replied)
Duration startAndCurrentDur = Duration.between(startTime, currentTime);
Duration activeAfterSecond = Duration.ofSeconds(5); // just an example

if(startAndCurrentDur.compareTo(activeAfterSecond) >= 0){ //enter if branch when activeAfterSecond equal or greater than startAndCurrentDur
   // do something
}


You can compare only values with the same type.

this is like wanting to compare the actual time/date with a period of 5 days ?? Is today after 5 days? You can add/subtract a Duration to/from an Instant (and then compare the resulting Instant with another); or compare the difference between two Instants with a Duration.

You need another Instant variable, with the lastTime (the currentTime of a previous step). Then, you may try something like this:
if (Duration.between (lastTime, currentTime).compareTo (duration) > 0) {
    // do Something
    lastTime = currentTime;
}

Note: edited for using compareTo().

This is the solution I went with. I wanna Note though, that you cannot use the >= operand for Durations (possibly because of the Duration format). I used the compareTo method instead.

Yes, of course. Duration is a class (a reference type). I'll correct it.


(possibly because of the Duration format)* No, you can never compare objects with >= or the like in Java (there are other programming languages that permit it in certain cases).


This is Java basics. You have value types (those that come with the language itself, like int, long, char, etc) and reference types (all classes, including those in the Java standard library, like String). A constant, variable or expression of a value type contains the value itself (the data), and that's copied with =, passed to a function or compared with ==. A constant, variable or expression of a reference type does not contain the data (which is apart and called an "object" or "instance") but a reference (an accessor) to it, and this reference is copied, passed or compared with ==.

You need an "anchor point" (start time, epoch, whatever you want to call it), effectively - the instant which you'd count as "duration 0", if you like.
For example, is 2024-08-14T17:05:00Z later than a duration of "one hour"? It is if the anchor point is 2024-08-14T16:00:00Z for example, but isn't if the anchor point is 2024-08-14T16:15:00Z.
Once you've decided on your "anchor point", it's easier - just add the duration to the anchor point to work out the instant at which you want the result to go from false to true, and then you've just got two instants to compare - which is supported very straightforwardly.
Without the anchor point, there is no meaningful comparison. That's not an implementation aspect: it's fundamental to what you're trying to compare.

Or, in fewer words, "duration (elapsed time) since when?"

Set a point, add time-to-elapse
Set your starting moment.
Instant start = Instant.now() ;

Specify your time to elapse.
Duration duration = Duration.ofSeconds( 7 ) ;

Calculate your future moment.
Instant due = start.plus( duration ) ;

Later, check to see if the current moment is past the moment due.
if
( 
    due.isBefore( Instant.now() )
) 
{ … time elapsed, proceed … } 
else 
{ … not yet due … }

Date-time math
You said (my edit):

Instants and Durations cannot be [compared] to one another

True, Instant & Duration cannot be compared against each other. But they can be used to perform date-time math, moving from one point in time (Instant) to another point of time into the future (positive Duration amount) or back into the past (negative Duration amount).
Timeline attachment
Be aware that a Duration by definition is not attached to the timeline. A Duration object represents a span of time, but without a specific beginning or ending.
If you want a span of time that is attached to the timeline, add the ThreeTen-Extra library to your project. There you will find the class Interval. Objects of the class Interval know their starting point and ending point on the timeline, defined as a pair of Instant objects.
Interval z = Interval.of( x , y ) ;

Drawing a timeline:
       Instant    Instant     Instant    Instant
past <-------a----b-----------------x----y---------> future


The two pairs a & b and x & y share the same Duration amount (four dashes each in our drawing).
true = Duration.between( a , b ).equals( Duration.between( x , y ) )  ;

But the Interval objects of each pare are not the same. The a-b interval happened earlier in time than the x-y interval.
false = Interval.of( a , b ).equals( Interval.of( x , y ) ) ;

